# Partial derivatives in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm trying to numerically solve a nonlinear system of equations in Julia. I'm using Newthon method. The only thing I don't know how to do, is to compute an Jacobian matrix.  So far I couldn't find the function to compute partial derivatives.

My system:

```
f(x1, x2) = 2*x2^2+x1^2
g(x1, x2) = (x1-1)^2 + (x2-1/2)^2
```

Thanks for your support,
Best regards,
Szymon.

Comment: I guess you could use https://github.com/JuliaDiff/ForwardDiff.jl

Comment: You can find some examples here https://github.com/crstnbr/julia-workshop/blob/master/4%20Ecosystem/4_overview.ipynb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me write as an answer what I already mentioned in the comments. You could use automatic differentiation to calculate the partial derivatives:

```
julia> using ForwardDiff

julia> f(x) = 2*x[2]^2+x[1]^2 # f must take a vector as input
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> g = x -> ForwardDiff.gradient(f, x); # g is now a function representing the gradient of f

julia> g([1,2]) # evaluate the partial derivatives (gradient) at some point x
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 8
```